# how to add values from a MySQL result-set while loop in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset, addition

I want to add the values of integer column "priority" obtained from the MySQL db by iterating resultset using while loop. My piece of code is as below:

```
    int TotalWestPriority = 0;
    int WestPty = 0;

    float lat = 0;
    float lon = 0;

    float Wb_SWLat = 0; // Currently holds some value from other process
    float Wb_NELat = 0; // Currently holds some value from other process
    float Wb_SWLon = 0; // Currently holds some value from other process
    float Wb_NELon = 0; // Currently holds some value from other process


//SQL Query:
    String qryVcl = "select priority, latitude, longitude from tbl_vcl";

    ResultSet Vp=stmt.executeQuery(qryVcl);

    while(Vp.next()){
        lat = Vp.getFloat("latitude");
        lon = Vp.getFloat("longitude");
        System.out.println("Total Lat received:"+lat);

        if(lat >=Wb_SWLat && lat <=Wb_NELat && lon>=Wb_SWLon && lon<=Wb_NELon){
            WestPty = Vp.getInt("priority");
            System.out.println("West Priority:"+WestPty);
        }
        }
```

---

Here, I'am able to print the result:-

West Priority:3

West Priority:2

I want to add those values and store in an integer.

how to add all the "westpty" from the iteration to "TotalWestPriority" ?

Comment: Hi, I just want to add the values coming out of while loop of the result set iteration and store in an integer. Any piece of code is highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean you want to sum up the all values retrieved in every iteration like `3+2=5`?

Comment: @PavneetSingh  Yes, you are right

Comment: then it's too simple ,`WestPty  = WestPty +Vp.getInt("priority");`

Comment: @PavneetSingh I'll try. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just accumulate them to another variable:

```
long total = 0L;
while (vp.next()) {
    lat = vp.getFloat("latitude");
    lon = vp.getFloat("longitude");

    if (lat >= Wb_SWLat && lat <= Wb_NELat && 
        lon >= Wb_SWLon && lon <= Wb_NELon) {

        westPty = Vp.getInt("priority");
        System.out.println("West Priority:"+WestPty);

        total += westPty;
    }
}

System.out.println("Total west priority: " + total);
```